# c++ code result output different depending execute method debug vs run

Tags: c++, random, srand

This program generates random string 3 times

Result is unique and different when debugged in eclipse with 'step into'

Result is same string 3 times when just executed

**Why is the result different depending on execution method, debug vs compile run?**

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>


string generaterandomstring(int length){
    int i, x, alphabetsize, asciioffset;
    string s1;

    alphabetsize = 26; // size of all lower case letters
    asciioffset = 97; // lower case letters start at 97

    srand ( time(NULL) );

    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        //generate random number
        x = rand() % alphabetsize + asciioffset;
        cout << "x: " << x;
        //get a letter
        cout << " char: " << char(x);
        //append it to string
        s1 = s1 + char(x);
        cout << " s1: " << s1 << endl;
    }
    return s1;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    string s1;
    int length = 3;

    srand ( time(NULL) );

    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        s1 = generaterandomstring(length);
        cout << "i is: " << i << " from main s1: " << s1 << endl;
        cout << rand() % 10 << endl;
    }

    cout << "!The End!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up what a "seed" is and how you are supposed to use it.

Comment: you're using the srand wrongly, that's why.

Comment: Unrelated: using `'a'` as `asciioffset` is much more readable.

Comment: debug step into mode result:x: 100 char: d s1: d
x: 113 char: q s1: dq
x: 114 char: r s1: dqr
i is: 0 from main s1: dqr
4
x: 97 char: a s1: a
x: 110 char: n s1: an
x: 104 char: h s1: anh
i is: 1 from main s1: anh
9
x: 100 char: d s1: d
x: 101 char: e s1: de
x: 118 char: v s1: dev
i is: 2 from main s1: dev
0
!The End!

Answer (score 1):

http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/

> The pseudo-random number generator is initialized using the argument passed as seed.
>
> For every different seed value used in a call to srand, the pseudo-random number generator can be expected to generate a different succession of results in the subsequent calls to rand.
> **Two different initializations with the same seed, instructs the pseudo-random generator to generate the same succession of results for the subsequent calls to rand in both cases**.

http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/

> Get the current calendar time as a time_t object.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you call `srand` **inside** `generaterandomstring`. During debug session, enough time passes between iterations (more than a second), so that `time(NULL)` returns different values each time. On free run, your program sets random seed to the same value and you get the same "random" value on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works in debug is that debug is slow enough that your reinitialization of srand with the current time in milliseconds is producing different random strings.  In release your code is too fast so srand is being reinitialized to the same list of random numbers.  As the other answer suggests you should call srand once and only once.  Though as an amusing aside if you throw a sleep 1 millisecond in there the problem will go away.